# sed/awk - add www. only if URL lacks www

Tags: bash, sed, awk

How to check if exists www in text? if not - add www, but if exists don't touch

For example

```
google.com
www.google.com
www.maps.google.com
test.test.test.com
```

Output should be

```
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.maps.google.com
www.test.test.test.com
```

I find some like this:

```
awk -F. '{print "www." $0; next}; {print}'
```

But this add always www

Comment: You need to do a test, and then add `www` if needed. Your `awk` does not test anything. See my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk '!/^www\./ {$0="www." $0}1' file
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.maps.google.com
www.test.test.test.com
```

Comment: You need to add a `\.` to the end of the test. What if the site listed is wwwaatsup.com?

Answer (score 0):

Using sed you can do:

```
sed '/^ *www/!s/\(.\)/www.\1/' file
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.maps.google.com
www.test.test.test.com
```

to make it inline editing:

```
sed -i.bak '/^ *www/!s/\(.\)/www.\1/' file
```

You can do this in awK:

```
awk -F'.' '$1!="www"{$0="www." $0}1' file
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.maps.google.com
www.test.test.test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the shell:

```
echo $1 | grep -q ^www. || echo -n www.; echo $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
$ site='www.stackoverflow.com'
$ [[ $site != www.* ]] && echo "www.$site" || echo "$site"
www.stackoverflow.com
$ site='stackoverflow.com'
$ [[ $site != www.* ]] && echo "www.$site" || echo "$site"
www.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby

```
# echo "test.test.test.com" | ruby -e 'puts "www.#{gets.chomp}" if $_ !~/www/ '
www.test.test.test.com
```